# Change a variable name with a raw_input

Tags: python, variable-names

Here is a beginners question:

I made a function that reads a txt file (selected by the user) and makes a list of many numbers contained in the file, called A. I called this function `open_file`.
Then I want to change the name of that list with the original name of the file, plus "`_values`"

My try

```
file_name = raw_inpunt('Give the name of the file:') # the user chooses the file
open_file (file_name) #A list is created

file_name +'_'+'values' = A
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to change the name of the variable to match the filename? Wouldn't that make it harder for the rest of the code to use the variable? If you really need to reference data by a name, consider using a `dict` instead.

Comment: there are multiple issues in your code: typo in `raw_input`, you don't save the returned value of `open_file()` so `A` is probably undefined, `"something" = anything` is not valid Python. How do you want to use `*_values` variable later?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using:

```
vars()[file_name+"_values"] = A
```

The reason it is not working because you are trying to save a list in a string.

Basically `file_name+"_"+"values"` is a string a not a variable. Hence you will get an error.

However I would highly suggest you saving the list of values for each filename in a dictionary.

```
values = dict()
values[file_name] = A
```

This is a more efficient way of storing values.

Comment: Thanks. And now, how do I convert the string to a variable so that it works?

Comment: I have updated my answer you can see the code. And yeah do accept it if you like =D

Comment: No no no no! this is a terrible way of changing a variable!

Comment: @JakobBowyer yeah that is not the appropriate way of storing. However if you do want to create a new variable from string this is the suggested way in Python.

Comment: This shows how it is *possible*, but I doubt it is *"the suggested way"*.

Comment: @ShawnChin yeah I have updated my code also. With the suggested way.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be doing this to a lot of files it would be better to store the lists in a dictionary rather than making a new variable for each.

```
results = {}
....
file_name = raw_input('Give the name of the file:') # the user chooses the file
open_file(file_name) #A list is created
results[file_name] = A
```